# XSL string extraction from SOAP response

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

first, i will provide code i already have. XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getUserDataResponse xmlns="http://wtp">
         <getUserDataReturn>Matt</getUserDataReturn>
         <getUserDataReturn>NY</getUserDataReturn>
      </getUserDataResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

That's XSLT i have:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <soapenv:Body>
                <getUserDataResponse xmlns="http://wtp">
                    <xsl:for-each select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/soapenv:getUserDataResponse/soapenv:getUserDataReturn">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </getUserDataResponse>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What i'm  trying to achieve is to extract only first element of array, in this case string "Matt, then put it like it was just regular response to send it further to another endpoint". I have no clue what could be incorrect.

Output i want:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getUserDataResponse xmlns="http://wtp">
         <getUserDataReturn>Matt</getUserDataReturn>
      </getUserDataResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Output i get now is just soap template without data.

Would be really grateful if someone could help :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you want can be achieved using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wtp="http://wtp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wtp:getUserDataResponse">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wtp:getUserDataReturn[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

To do it the way you have started, you would have to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:wtp="http://wtp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <getUserDataResponse xmlns="http://wtp">
                <getUserDataReturn>
                    <xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/wtp:getUserDataResponse/wtp:getUserDataReturn[1]" />
                </getUserDataReturn>
            </getUserDataResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note the use of a prefix to select elements in the default `"http://wtp"` namespace.